# delay before binding template angular

Tags: javascript, angular

this is kind of relate to ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError again.

in my situation, I have a parameter 'data' which I recover from ajax call.
this data is used to create child via @input directive. I wish the binding only occurs when data is defined. but I have no idea how to do that with angular

```
export class UserComponent{
    data: any


    constructor(
        private userService: UserService){
            this.userService.getUser()
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.data = result;
            }
       }
    );
}
```

because the way it works, angular will display an ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError, which I understand why, but how to ask angular to wait for the callback to be done and data to be != from undefined before start binding and stuff, the goal is to have some child initialized with the real value coming from the database.

If I should wait for the end of the cycle before binding "real" data, it's fine, but how to do it without having this error, (and please without using `setTimeout` as it looks a lot of rubbish !).

Thanks

```
<!--the template if it matter --><somechildtag [data]="data" ></somechildtag>
```

Comment: every answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787038/how-to-manage-angular2-expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-exception-w didn't help in my scenario :s

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load your component with `ng-container`.

For example:

```
    <div *ngIf="data?.length > 0">
        <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="myChildComponent;
              ngModuleFactory: childComponentsModule;"></ng-container>
    </div>
```

So, you will *render* your child only if your `data` object is *populated*.

In your component:

```
private childComponentsModule: NgModuleFactory<any>;

constructor(private compiler: Compiler){
  this.childComponentsModule = compiler.compileModuleSync(ChildComponentsModule);
}
```

You can see a more detailed example of how to load dynamically a component here:

[Angular2: Use Pipe to render templates dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143956/angular2-use-pipe-to-render-templates-dynamically)

Angular's documentation:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgComponentOutlet-directive.html

Comment: never see this ngcomponentOutlet before, thanks for different link

Comment: @ssbb No problem man. Is a very flexible solution, since I discovered it, it has saved my life! I am now rendering dynamic form inputs, dynamic menu options, etc... Is a very powerful tool in my opinion. Good luck in your project! ;)