# angular - best practice for using conditionally different layouts in a component

Tags: angular, angular-template, ng-template, ng-container, ng-content

Suppose we have a couple of components that each of them should have different layout/ui (templates) conditioned with display dimensions.
My solution is to create such a component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints} from '@angular/cdk/layout';

@Component({
    selector: 'ui-switcher',
    template: `
        <ng-content *ngIf="isSmall" select="mobile"></ng-content>
        <ng-content *ngIf="!isSmall" select="web"></ng-content>
`
})
export class UiSwitcherComponent {
    public isSmall: boolean;

    constructor(breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {
        breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.Small, Breakpoints.XSmall]).subscribe(result => {
            this.isSmall = result.matches;
        });
    }

}
```

and use it in this way:

```
<ui-switcher>
    <web>
        <!-- a ui suited for large screens -->
    </web>

    <mobile>
        <!-- a very different ui suited for small mobile screen displays-->

    </mobile>
</ui-switcher>
```

This solution may have some pitfalls. For example we can't use same templaterefs in `<mobile>` and `<web>` sections. (above we used `#searchInput` and `#searchInput2`).
What is the ***best practices*** for such situations?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are just adding a CSS class if `isSmall` is `false`.
You can solve this by simply having 1 input (not 2), and add the class conditionally.

So, instead of rendering conditionally 2 blocks of HTML that are identical... You render 1 block with a conditional CSS class.

Example below:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ui-switcher',
    template: `
        <input class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'mr-2': !isSmall}"> 
        type="text" (keyup)="this.search(searchInput.value)">
`
})
```

Now, if your content would **really** change and you need more than simple `*ngIf`'s... Then, a good solution is to use the in tamplate `if...else` or even `if...elseif...else`.

Reference here: [How to use *ngIf else in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else-in-angular)

For more conditional Class usage, check this post: [Angular: conditional class with *ngClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269179/angular-conditional-class-with-ngclass)

Hope it helped! ;)

**Update:**

The OP was referring to a change that only affected the CSS class, but if you want to dynamically load a component into a block of code... I would say that you go with [ngComponentOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet).

Example:

```
        <fieldset *ngFor="let component of components">
            <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="component.name;
                                ngModuleFactory: dynamicComponentsModule;"></ng-container>
        </fieldset>
```

The good thing about this approach is that you could created a map, and for each option you have a `Component` associated with it. Example:

```
map = [
   'option1': ComponentForOption1,
   'option2': ComponentForOption2
];
```

I would suggest this post that provides more a complete example:

[Dynamic template based on value rather than variable with ngTemplateOutlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44073964/dynamic-template-based-on-value-rather-than-variable-with-ngtemplateoutlet/44074504#44074504)

With this, in this answer, I provided information on how to have:

1. Dynamic CSS classes
2. Conditional HTML with in-template `if...elseif...else`
3. Dynamic component loading

Comment: No, changes are more than just a css class. Suppose we have many layout changes that considering it in all components are cumbersome. We like to handle it in a single component.

Comment: @Fartab Hey! I have updated my answer with an explanation on how to load component dynamically. If something is not clear let me know. Cheers! :D