# Angular *ngFor render different objects from base list

Tags: angular, polymorphism

In my Angular project I have a list of reports. The list/array has a base class because the list can contain different types of reports. But although the list is of type: `ReturnReport` the actuall items in the list can be of type: `SafetyReport` or `DraftSafetyReport`. The reason for these 2 objects is that they contain different data but needed to be shown in 1 and the same datatable.

```
export abstract class ReturnReport {

}

export class DraftSafetyReport extends ReturnReport {

}

export class SafetyReport extends ReturnReport {
    id?: string;
    status?: string;
    safetyReportSummary!: SafetyReportSummary;
}
```

In my component I have the following so both types of reports can be in the list:

```
  reportList$: BehaviorSubject<ReturnReport[]> = new BehaviorSubject<ReturnReport[]>([]);
```

So far so good, and I understand how it all works, but I'm facing an issue when rendering in my HTML.

```
<tbody *ngIf="(reportList$ | async) as reportlist" class="">
            <tr *ngFor="let report of reportlist" class="h-12">
                <td>{{report.safetyReportSummary.occurrenceDate | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

The error is:

> Property 'safetyReportSummary' does not exist on type 'ReturnReport'.

I know why, because the type of the list is ReturnReport. So the property `safetyReportSummary` does not exist. But how do I achieve this? Should I look in the corner of ng-template or ng-templateOutlet? Do I somehow cast the object before I render a specific HTML

I use Angular 15.2.3.

Any questions, please let me know!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since the objects have a `DraftSafetyReport | SafetyReport` type, there's no elegant workaround I don't think.

You could create a new function that gets the value you want based on the attribute

```
getValue(attribute: string, obj: SafetyReport | DraftSafetyReport): any {
    if (attribute in obj) {
        return obj[attribute];
    }
}
```

Other options would be to create a pipe that casts the object for you, or use the type `any` instead, but neither are not my favorite options

Comment: After some more search I came accross: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58584555/render-dynamic-template-based-on-type What is your opinion about something like this? See answer.

Comment: I do have to add a //@ts-ignore above: obj[attribute] => Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'SafetyReport | DraftSafetyReport'. No sure why, though

Comment: The getTypeName function from the answer seems good enough to be honest. I tried something more generic, but either way looks good to me. With that approach you may have to create more functions for other attributes, but still, it's a good answer to me. It also fixes the any type issue

Answer (score 0):

You could use a helper function that checks the type of your list elements:

**.ts**

```
 getSafetyReportSummary(report: SafetyReport | DraftSafetyReport) {
    const _temp = report as SafetyReport
    if (_temp.safetyReportSummary) {
      return _temp.safetyReportSummary.occurrenceDate
    }
    else return null
  }
```

**.html**

```
<tbody *ngIf="(reportList$ | async) as reportlist" class="">
    <tr *ngFor="let report of reportlist" class="h-12">
        <td *ngIf="getSafetyReportSummary(report)">Date: {{getSafetyReportSummary(report) | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**example:**

```
safetyReport = {
    id: "id",
    status: "status",
    safetyReportSummary: {
      occurrenceDate: Date(),
    }

  }
  draftSafetyReport = {
    name: "test"
  }

  reportList$: BehaviorSubject<ReturnReport[]> = new BehaviorSubject<ReturnReport[]>([this.safetyReport, this.draftSafetyReport]);
```

**output:**

[image]